# why '^(?[0-P<id>9]+)/$' is not a valid regular expression in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

i just created a new different url and view.after that this error is showing..
the newly created url and views are the following

```
url(r'^$', views.DeleteContent, name="delete"),
```

View :

```
def DeleteContent(request, id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('accounts:login')

    todo = get_object_or_404(ToDo, id=id)
    todo.delete()

    return render(request,"index.html")
```

Comment: Because it's not a valid regular expression *anywhere*? Try dropping it into e.g. http://regex101.com and you'll see the errors explained.

Comment: You need to move this `[0-` part after `<id>`, so it will be `^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$`, which means an `id` parameter which is a number.

Comment: But if that's what you mean `\d` is more idiomatic than `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', DeleteContent, name='delete')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not invalid in Django, it is invalid anywhere. I think you have just mistyped it.

The regex `^(?[0-P<id>9]+)/$` is totally invalid, drop it in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), as [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) said, and see what it says:

- `(?` Incomplete group structure
- `)` Incomplete group structure

You can simply have a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#captured-arguments-are-always-strings):

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive)
```

This is a sample url regex for year. See how it is formatted.

You should write your regex like in order to make it valid:

```
^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$
```

It means an `id` parameter, which is numeric (`[0-9]+`)

*EDIT:* Or you can use `\d+` instead of `[0-9]+`, as it is more straightforward and says **"`id` is a `digit`"**.